# Java: deep copy of object with Runnable member with copy constructor

Tags: java, copy-constructor, runnable, deep-copy

I have a class `character` that I'd like to create a copy of before a certain event so that if the user screws up he can retry with the copy. To implement this I use the copy constructor like this:

```
public class character
    implements Serializable
{
private String                          name;
private HashMap<String,Integer>         values = new HashMap<>();
private ArrayList<String>               traits = new ArrayList<>();
private enums.playerRelations           playerRelation;
private static character                playerCharacter = new character();
private transient Runnable              combatAI;
private transient Runnable              tradingAI;
private ArrayList<character>            companions = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<item>                 inventory = new ArrayList<>();
private int                             maximumInventorySize = 20;
private int                             maximumSkillSlots = 10;
private transient ArrayList<Pair<skill,Boolean>>  skills = new ArrayList<>();
private int                             portraitResource = R.drawable.ic_bear;
private event                           eventContext;

public character(character o)
{
    name                    = o.name;
    values                  = new HashMap<>(o.values);
    traits                  = new ArrayList<>(o.traits);
    playerRelation          = o.playerRelation;
    combatAI                = o.combatAI;
    tradingAI               = o.tradingAI;
    companions              = new ArrayList<>(o.companions);
    inventory               = new ArrayList<>(o.inventory);
    maximumInventorySize    = o.maximumInventorySize;
    maximumSkillSlots       = o.maximumSkillSlots;
    skills                  = new ArrayList<>(o.skills);
    portraitResource        = o.portraitResource;
    eventContext            = o.eventContext;
}

// ...
}
```

However, I don't know how to deep clone a `Runnable` object. How can I deep copy those? Is that at all possible using the copy constructor?

I notice that `Runnable` is different from the other members of `character` insofar that the part of concern is stored within a function rather than an attribute...

Comment: Don't use `Runnable` but a strategy interface of your own which includes a proper clone method. As a side note, your class looks very overburdened with properties, splitting and/or grouping them would be an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you know about, say, `combatAI` is that it is `Runnable` then you can't deep copy it - it has no depth so to speak - it's just `Runnable`.

You may want to rethink this approach and explicitly have check points in the game (?) so that you could create a `combatAI` and the rest of the state from the check point data.

Also note that your copy of `inventory` is just one level deep, the original and the new `character`s share the same `item`s. Same deal with `companions`